# Positioning two DIVs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu consisting of a couple of DIVs and a promo image that I cannot display next to the said menu. I'm using an inline-block; in the image and block in the menu, and one is displayed below the other.

```css
 .menu{
     background-color: white;
     color: #707070;
     height: 50px;
     width: 200px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 1px solid;
     text-align: middle;
     margin-left: 13px;
     margin-top: 30px;
     display: block;
    }
    
    .collapsible {
     background-color: white;
     display: block;
     color: #707070;
     height: 50px;
     width: 200px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 1px solid;
     text-align: middle;
     margin-left: 13px;
    }
    
    .content {
     display: none;
     text-align: center;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: white;
     color: #707070;
     height: 50px;
     width: 200px;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin-left: 13px;
    }
    
    .advert{
     height: 240px;
     width: 800px;
     margin-left: 500px;
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     float: top;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="menu">MENU</button>
     <button class="collapsible">Categories &#x2BC6;</button>
      <div class="content">
       <p>1</p>
      </div>
     <button class="collapsible">Information &#x2BC6;</button>
      <div class="content">
       <p>2</p>
      </div>
     <button class="collapsible">Contact Us &#x2BC6;</button>
      <div class="content">
       <p>3</p>
      </div>
     <button class="collapsible">Follow Us &#x2BC6;</button>
      <div class="content">
       <p>4</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <img src="img/promo_image.png" class="advert">
    </div>
```

Adding some more details so the form doesn't refuse my question.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - WE NEED YOUR CSS!

Answer (score 0):

I have arranged it in horizontal  by using inline flex for div.

```css
.inline-flex{
  display: inline-flex;
}

.menu{
    background-color: white;
    color: #707070;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: middle;
    margin-left: 13px;
    /* margin-top: 30px; */
    display: block;
    }

.collapsible {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    color: #707070;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: middle;
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.content {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    color: #707070;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.advert{
    height: 240px;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-flex">
<button class="menu">MENU</button>
    <button class="collapsible">Categories &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Information &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Contact Us &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Follow Us &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
</div>

<div>
<img src="img/promo_image.png" class="advert">
</div>
```

Comment: The menu is now inline, but the image was somewhat in the right spot

Comment: @DanielKlas is there is any other changes do you want ?

Comment: @DanielKlas if u need image also at the inline block then move the image div to the menu div

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `float: top` does not exist in css.
There are many ways to what you want.. For example, you could simply make the advertisements position absolute:

```css
.menu {
  background-color: white;
  color: #707070;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: middle;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  color: #707070;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: middle;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  color: #707070;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.advert {
  height: 240px;
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="menu">MENU</button>
  <button class="collapsible">Categories &#x2BC6;</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Information &#x2BC6;</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Contact Us &#x2BC6;</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Follow Us &#x2BC6;</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="img/promo_image.png" class="advert">
</div>
```

But I would suggest you use css grid or flex. For example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 213px 1fr;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu{
    background-color: white;
    color: #707070;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: middle;
    margin-left: 13px;
    display: block;
}

.collapsible {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    color: #707070;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: middle;
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.content {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    color: #707070;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.advert{
    height: 240px;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div>
<button class="menu">MENU</button>
    <button class="collapsible">Categories &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Information &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Contact Us &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Follow Us &#x2BC6;</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
</div>

<div>
<img src="img/promo_image.png" class="advert">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work either, however you gave me a different perspective on this, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. If you're new to css grid, there are some good tutorials on [freecodecamp](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/css-grid/)